# How to modify currency format using DataFormatString in GridView

Tags: asp.net, formatting

How would I display the value, for example:

```
851839.850000
```

To show its currency equivalent with comma and period formatting:

```
£851,839.85
```

by using `DataFormatString`?  Currently I have `£{0:c2}`, but clearly this is not enough, as it gives me

```
£851839.850000
```

Comment: What does `£{0:c2}` give you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out that the original value that was being bound was actually in a string format.  Simpling making sure it was incoming as a Decimal allowed the formatting:

> £{0:C}

to work precisely as expected and format into a correct decimal value with a £(British Sterling) to be placed before the value.

Answer (score 2):

Define culture like

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" 
    CodeFile="Search.aspx.cs" Inherits="Search_aspx" Title="Search"  
    UICulture="hi-IN" Culture="hi-IN" %>
```

Find culture code from [this list](http://www.massimilianobianchi.info/max/articles/22/UI-culture-list-and-codes.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could try   `£{0:N2}`, see if that works.

Currency formatting is based on the current `NumberFormatInfo`.  `C2` ought to work for you, depending on your current culture, but since it doesn't you might want to look at the [NumberFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx) information.

There's more about currency formatting here:  [The Currency ("C") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#CFormatString)

Answer (score 0):

TO display in text box..Try

```
textbox.text = Format(Value,"$#,###.00")
```

Comment: The question was how to display the value in a GridView